# Using sqlalchemy in pyramid_jqm

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I know that pyramid comes with a scaffold for sqlalchemy. But what if I'm using the pyramid_jqm scaffold. How would you integrate or use sqlalchemy then? When I create a model.py and import from sqlalchemy I get an error that he couldnt find the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup your project in the same way that the alchemy scaffold is constructed. Put "sqlalchemy" in your setup.py requires field and run "python setup.py develop" to install the dependency. This is all just python and unrelated to Pyramid.

Comment: Thanks!! That makes so much sense. I was struggling and tried to install the dependency manually but then zope was missing too. I have just put them both in the requires field and the server starts w/o erroring. Now I need to figure out how to actually use sqlalchemy in my app.